# Webpack Dev Server Opening Vue App in the Wrong Port

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have a full stack app with Vue running webpack-dev-server and node running on express.

My webpack-dev-server is configured to open Vue on `port 8080`, and express listens on `port 8081`.

However, my Vue app recently started defaulting to running on `port 8081` when started, even though my webpack config is as follows:

- webpack.dev.config.js

  ```js
  const HOST = process.env.HOST
  const PORT = process.env.PORT && Number(process.env.PORT)
  ```

and Vue config is

- config/index.js

  ```js
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8080,
  ```
- vue and webpack dev dependencies

  `"babel-core": "^6.22.1",
  "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
  "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
  "webpack": "^4.33.0",
  "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.0",
  "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"`
- vue and webpack dependencies

  `"vue": "^2.6.10",
  "vue-loader": "^14.2.4",
  "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
  "vuex": "^3.1.1",
  "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"`

Anyone know what might be causing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that a [Vue webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) setup (for Vue CLI v2)?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the dependencies in package.json

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I asked you

Comment: no, it is version 3.4

Comment: Again, that is not what I asked you. Was this project created using the Vue CLI v2 with the webpack template linked above? If not, then how **exactly** is `webpack.dev.config.js` and `config/index.js` incorporated into your webpack-dev-server?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I created using CLI v2 with the command `vue init webpack "app name"`

Comment: So what does your comment _"no, it is version 3.4"_ mean? **What** is version 3.4?

Comment: that is the current installed version of vue

Comment: But your dependencies say `^2.6.10`. Also, Vue 3 isn't even out yet. This is all very confusing

Comment: If I go to cmd and enter `vue --version` the result is `3.4.0` That's probably part of the issue, semver mix up

Comment: Right, that's the Vue CLI. You said you created the app with Vue CLI v2 though so still very confusing. How **exactly** are you starting your app?

Comment: I have an `npm run dev` script, and `dev` reads `"webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080 --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js"`

Comment: Ok, so your project is still using the Vue CLI v2 webpack template. This is fine (just deprecated). Your config looks ok (see [docs](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/backend.html)). So you're saying when you run `npm run dev`, it starts a server on port 8081? Could be you have an environment variable overriding the port config. Try using the `env` command (or `SET` on Windows) to see what's defined in your shell.

Comment: the only `env var` defined is a JWT private key

Comment: `webpack-dev-server` utilizes [this package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port/blob/master/index.js#L27) to determine which port to use when booting. There are 2 possibilities. You still have something running on `8080` which you can find by using a `netstat` or `ps aux` command, or you have an error in your code which can actually trickle down and explode the port assignment, too. To eliminate #2, delete everything from your entry file and run it. It should work if it's not #1.

Comment: Nice! There was nothing running on 8080, so option 2 worked! Thank you both for your time. Go ahead and add the answer for some cred if you want it.